# Optocoupler with 220V DC

Tags: microcontroller, opto-isolator

i need help from you. I want to use 220V DC input to microcontroller. For this purpose i have to use optocoupler, so how can i choose optocoupler with input for 220V DC?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how much current is needed by the diode in the opto for triggering the photo-transistor? If it is (say) 5mA, you need to "lose" 218V across a resistor and this means you can calculate the value of resistor. Will the opto sometimes get reverse biased with 200VDC through the resistor - check what reverse voltage you can survive with OR use a series protection diode.

Comment: The input side of the opto coupler is an IR led and only requires a few mA at a low voltage and are all basically the same. The isolation voltage may vary but this is usually in the kV region.  Basically you are going top have to drop most of the 220V to operate the input.

Comment: Please confirm that your source voltage is DC. Where is this 220 Volts DC coming from, and what is the purpose of the optocoupler exactly? Please draw up a schematic or sketch and upload to any public image sharing site, then provide the link here, so someone can edit it into your question.

Comment: I want ot make one device for Power plant. The power supplay is 220V DC. I will use Microchip for this device and i need few inputs and outputs. For the outputs i will use relay, but for inputs i need something like optocouplers. This device is very simple, i just need few inputs to the microcontroller but the input voltage is 220V DC.

Comment: Are you saying that you need to convert the 220VDC to suitable power level for the micro? I.e. you need a voltage regulator?

Comment: no no. The device will work with adaptor with 5V. Only the inputs and outputs will be 220V

Comment: It is the same like in this picture, but i will use 220V instead 12V                        http://www.google.bg/imgres?imgurl=http://www.islavici.ro/cursuri/conducere%2520sist%2520cu%2520calculatorul/PICbook/7_chapter/12.gif&imgrefurl=http://www.islavici.ro/cursuri/conducere%2520sist%2520cu%2520calculatorul/PICbook/7_04chapter.htm&h=257&w=544&sz=5&tbnid=u5UH5-Ht1T2JoM:&tbnh=57&tbnw=120&zoom=1&usg=__vN-KljTmdbMs2BXVDEUg2vSe4Yk=&docid=a4XyimNlv9JEuM&sa=X&ei=xvSlUaOCKMuAPebIgdAM&ved=0CDIQ9QEwAg&dur=563

Comment: So is it possible?

Comment: Yes. You will need to drop 218V @10mA for the input LED. This gives a resistor value of about 22K. The resistor will have to dissipate just over 2 Watts so I would suggest using a 5 Watt resistor to keep it cool.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is a one-off project, this is what you can do:

- Obtain a 220 Volt **incandescent** miniature night light bulb, of power rating 2 to 8 watts, such as the ones on [this page](http://www.lamps2udirect.com/pages/browse-More-Lamps2udirect.php/Miniature_Bulbs/Night_Light_Bulbs/320/36).
- Use an optocoupler like the PC817, that can withstand 50 mA current on the input LED, but works from as little as 5 mA or so.
- Connect this lightbulb in series with the optocoupler's input:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmbpbz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The incandescent light is not affected by supply voltage being DC or AC.

At the wattage suggested, the current through the bulb would be between 9 and 30 mA. This is sufficient to operate the optocoupler.

Comment: I think your circuit is not safe enough. From the datasheet of PC817, we know two facts:1. the max value of Vf is around 1.4V;2.the Absolute Maximum Ratings of If is 50 mA. so nearly all the voltage is on the lamb and max the current is around 36.3 mA. A device can not work in condition  close to absolute maximun ratings for a long time

Comment: @oilpig While 36.3 mA isn't really that close to 50 mA, consider the suggested 8 Watt upper limit as yet another "Absolute Maximum" - use a lower wattage for a greater margin of safety if you like. If one cannot find a 6 Watt or lower rated bulb, just put two of those 8 Watt bulbs in series. Solved.

Comment: I would add a reverse biased diode across the inputs of the opto coupler when using it in a high voltage circuit that most likely uses a manual installation step to attach it into the device being monitored. The diode can help protect the optocoupler in the case that the 220V connection happens to be connected in reverse or if an AC voltage was mistakenly connected instead.

Comment: @MichaelKaras I specifically asked in comments about AC v/s DC, purely to determine whether the AC case needs to be handled. Reversal of leads on a 220 Volt DC line? Hmm, whoever is fitting the stuff up is likely to have bigger problems than merely a blown optocoupler. :-) However, it's a  simple change, I'll do it.

Comment: The cold resistance of the bulb is much lower than its hot resistance. The initial current through the LED could well exceed its rating. What advantage does a bulb have over a fixed resistor in this circuit? Why not skip the opto-coupler all together and just use the light from the bulb to operate an LDR or photodiode pointed at the bulb. Then it won't matter if the circuit is connected the wrong way around. (no diode needed.)

Comment: @JImDearden Good point on the bulb + LDR. Worth making it into an answer. The idea behind the bulb is that instead of merely dissipating the surplus power as heat, it can be used as a visual indicator of line status.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh  What happens when/if the bulb burns out?

Comment: @mikeY Since I am not aware of any electronic component that is sure to never fail, I'm sure you'll provide some illumination on the matter.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh I appreciate that a bulb can be used and as you rightly say it is a visual indicator and does help with getting rid of some of the power as light rather than heat. I have used filament bulbs to charge capacitors (mains strobe) for exactly the same reason. The non linear action of the bulb (low - high resistance) in this case could still be a problem if the initial current through the LED is too high. Perhaps I'm just being over picky on this small point. Your answer, as it stands, would work. If you want to put up the LDR version, be my guest.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh  Actually I was just asking a question.  What does happen if the bulb burns out?  Does the PC817 chip fry giving its life to save the MCU?  I think that is what should happen - the whole reason for the opto coupler is the separation and protection, right?

Comment: @mikeY If the bulb dies, the optocoupler never receives any input, so nothing gets to the MCU. No optocouplers were harmed in the making of this design :-)

Comment: @AnindoGhosh  Oh, duh.  That makes sense.  The burned out bulb doesn't conduct, makes an open circuit, everything stops.  Wasn't thinking.  Thanks.